# Django Admin Inline Not Showing Foreign Key Choices from Abstract Model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an app that has an abstract base model:

```
class Approval(models.Model):
    approver=models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    decision=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=APPROVAL_TYPES)
    response=models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

I then have a series of models that are based on that abstract one, all which generally define a foreign key (as they'll be related to different models) as well as a few fields unique to that model. Something like this:

```
class InternshipApproval(Approval):
    req=models.ForeignKey(InternshipRequest)
    priority=models.BooleanField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Approval for %s" % (self.req)
```

When I then set up my admin for, say, the InternshipRequest model (any model that one of my subclasses might be related to, actually), I want to include the InternshipApproval model as an inline:

```
class InternshipApprovalInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model=InternshipApproval
    max_num=1
    extra=1
    can_delete=False

...

class InternshipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines= [InternshipApprovalInline]
```

All is good and well, except that, when the admin interface is loaded, the "approver" field from the abstract base model is an empty select element.

I have verified that, if I instead include that field on the sub model (instead of the abstract base model), it will properly get the full User queryset (or any filtering I want to do on it using various strategies I've found here on SO). I've also verified that if I register the InternshipApproval model admin separately, then the admin pane there (i.e. not as an inline) will properly get the full user queryset as well even when the field is on the abstract base model. Finally, I've verified that the approver field still works ... I can use the little plus sign next to it to add a new User, and that user shows up and properly saves (but then disappears again from the select element if I go in to edit the model). So there's something about having a foreign key field on an abstract model that doesn't let it pass the queryset through to an inline (I can't override it, can't pass initial values, etc. etc.). What is it that I'm missing, here? (Note that I'm on Django 1.5.1) Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `to_field='username'`? Maybe the Django Inlines don't like that.

Comment: You could also try adding `fk_name='username'` on the inline class.

Comment: I'm in an organization where everyone has an internal unique "netid" assigned to them, and so many of our apps use that for usernames, various primary keys, etc. (simplifies things across many platforms, dbs, etc.). Regardless, that isn't the issue, unfortunately; when the model is keyed to the user id I see the same issue. I'll try setting the fk_name property and report back ... it may be that Django is getting confused as to which relationship to latch onto because of the abstract class, so maybe that'll help.